# XML Schema for collection of components of any of defined type

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation, xml-validation

I have defined components of types `inputTextType` and `inputEmailType` (their definitions are not important here). I need to have `components` collection of any number inputText and/or inputEmail, in any order (example: text, email, text, text). I've tried:

```
<xs:complexType name="componentsType">
    <xs:choice>
        <xs:element name="inputText" type="inputTextType" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0"/>
        <xs:element name="inputEmail" type="inputEmailType" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0"/>
    </xs:choice>
</xs:complexType>
```

but then when validating XML

```
<components>
    <inputText>
        <label>label 1</label>
        <name>as</name>
    </inputText>
    <inputText>
        <label>label 2</label>
        <name>ghyyy6</name>
    </inputText>
    <inputEmail>
        <label>drg</label>
        <name>rgtght</name>
    </inputEmail>
</components>
```

I have an error `cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'inputEmail'. One of '{inputText}' is expected.`. XML is correct (I need it). How should I fix the XSD?

For the XML above I changed XSD to

```
<xs:complexType name="componentsType">
    <xs:choice>
        <xs:element name="inputText" type="inputTextType" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0"/>
        <xs:element name="inputEmail" type="inputEmailType" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0"/>
    </xs:choice>
</xs:complexType>
```

and it worked but then I'm not able to define text, email, text, text but only first all texts and then all emails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the occurrence constraints up to `xs:choice`:

```
<xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
    <xs:element name="inputText" type="inputTextType"/>
    <xs:element name="inputEmail" type="inputEmailType"/>
</xs:choice>
```